Color and size filter on the store page
I have a question about the shop page.
I am designing a full stack store with NextJS.
My question is not about Next itself. It is about how to filter products with it's color and size( product features).
I want to have a series of features on the site. For example,

color (blue, red, yellow, etc.),
size (sm, md, lg, xl, 2xl),
brand, etc.

I want to display the entire list of hats when someone searches for a hat on the site. In addition to that, display the list of all the features for the hat as a filter next to it.
The problem is that, for example, I have 20 different colors on the site, but the colors of the hats are only 5. How should I do this filter?
Or, for example, hats have the color feature, but they don't have the size feature - shoes don't have the color feature, they have the size feature.
How can I manage this system so that when someone searches for the word "shoes", no color filter will appear at all?
When searching for a hat, choose the color and not the size.
The solution that seems to me is to first get the list of products in the backend. Then I will do a for on the products and put all the features in a feature_list. For example, colors_list and sizes_list and...
Then I will send these to the front end.
But this process definitely takes half an hour.
Once he has to find the products themselves. Then call the for method again and check it.
Isn't there a better way?
Even if you have a small idea and opinion, I would appreciate it. Maybe it will help me.

Broadly speaking you can run two queries. One for the main result set which usually includes paginations. The second is for just the filters. This latter might be several joins and unions, but it will tell you the valid subset of your overall filters. This will not only get you hat-specific colors, but only the colors that are available for the given query. This latter query is also cacheable.

thank you @ChrisHaas . yes. i can get for example yellow color from frontend. but problem is this: when user search without any filter, how can I select just 5 colors that hats have...

I'm saying the PHP tells the front-end what the filters are in the first place. You have 20 possible filters. Someone searches, and as part of the result set you also say "here are the valid filters", which will be a subset (including possibly the entire set) of the possible filters.

Are you using php or python?

@NigelRen no. I'm using javascript but I need solving method of this problem and after, Run it in JavaScript. in any language, if you want to make a shop products filter with products color, brand or size, what you do...
